# Is it possible to create a new variable based on a number of rules and multiple other variables?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I need to create a new variable summarising whether a participant has received treatment.

The data I start with looks like this...

```
df <- tribble(
  ~diagnosis_A, ~treatment_A, ~diagnosis_B, ~treatment_B, ~diagnosis_C, ~treatment_C,
  0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA,
  1, 1, 0, NA, 0, NA,
  1, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA,
  1, 1, 1, 1, 0, NA,
  1, 0, 1, 0, 0, NA,
  1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA,
  1, 0, 1, 1, 0, NA,
  1, 0, 1, 0, NA, NA,
  1, 1, 1, 0, NA, NA)
```

There are multiple diagnoses and for each diagnosis there is a corresponding treatment column indicating whether they have received treatment for the condition (e.g. diagnosis_A / treatment_A).

If the participant did not receive a diagnosis (i.e. diagnosis = 0), then they will not have been asked if they received treatment (i.e. treatment = NA).

The first row represents someone who reported no diagnoses.
The second row represents someone who reported a diagnosis and was treated for it.
The third row represents someone who reported a diagnosis and wasn't treated for it.

I need to create a new column named 'received_treatment' that should look like this...

```
df <- tribble(
  ~diagnosis_A, ~treatment_A, ~diagnosis_B, ~treatment_B, ~diagnosis_C, ~treatment_C, ~received_treatment,
  0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA,
  1, 1, 0, NA, 0, NA, 1,
  1, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0,
  1, 1, 1, 1, 0, NA, 1,
  1, 0, 1, 0, 0, NA, 0,
  1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, 1,
  1, 0, 1, 1, 0, NA, 1,
  1, 0, 1, 0, NA, NA, NA,
  1, 1, 1, 0, NA, NA, 1)
```

The new variable needs to take into consideration a number of rules:

- If the participant recieved no diagnoses the new variable should be NA (e.g. row 1).
- 1 should indicate a participant received treatment for at least one of the diagnoses they received.
- 0 should indicate a participant received a diagnosis for at least one condition but didn't receive treatment for any of them.
- If the participant is missing a diagnosis and hasn't received treatment for any other diagnosis (e.g. row 8), then their received_treatment variable should be NA.
- If the participant is missing a diagnosis but has received treatment another diagnosis (e.g. row 9), then their received_treatment variable should be 1.

I would like to have R code (preferably using tidyverse syntax) to create this new variable within the mutate function. I tried using case_when, but I couldn't work out how to do it succinctly without writing out every possible iteration. If tidyverse is not possible, then base would also be great.

Comment: Hi Tom! This is quite a complicated thing you are asking for. Have you written some code for it already? Reading what you wrote, it feels less like a question and more like you are giving orders. You do know StackOverflow isn't a code writing service, right?

Comment: Hi Mark! I am aware, thanks. I opted to keep it as succinct as possible and not share lots of failed code, did not mean for it to come across as orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below code

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(diag=rowSums(across(starts_with('diag'))),
         trt=rowSums(across(starts_with('treat')), na.rm=T),
         received_treatment=case_when(
           diag==0 ~ NA,
           diag>0 & trt>0 ~ 1,
           diag>0 & trt==0 ~ 0,
           is.na(diag) & trt==0 ~ NA,
           is.na(diag) & trt>0 ~ 1
         )
         ) %>% select(-c(diag,trt))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

[image]

Comment: There is no need for `rowwise()`.